# Acess VBA: Runtime error 2282

Tags: ms-access, vba

I get the following error

```
VB Runtime Error 2282: The format in which you are attempting to output the current object is not available
```

when I try to run this VBA string:

```
Private Sub Print_Click()
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "File_name", acFormatPDF, MyPath & MyFilename, True
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

`MyPath` comes from the Red arrow.
`MyFilename` comes from the Blue arrow.

[image]

Comment: How about a [mcve]?

Comment: what are the values for MyPath and MyFilename and do you have access to write to that location?

Comment: Sounds like the (a) report is not open.

Comment: @JonTout right question :) I have edited the post to answer to your question

Comment: @Gustav sorry, I don't undestrand. may you explain better?

Comment: Assuming this will run on a local PC...
My_Path would equal to "C:\Users\Public\Music\" (without the quotes) and My_Filename would be "File_name.pdf" (again, without the quotes).

Can you post the VBA that creates those variables?

Comment: `"File_name"` must be the report name. -- And: which Access version?

Comment: This happened once at my office with and old version of Access and the problem was that the PC did not have installed any Add-In or Adobe able to create PDF files, not even manually. Could be that?

Comment: Please add a Debug.Print MyPath,   MyFilename   and determine if MyFilename has a ".PDF" suffix